# Rails : ExecJS::ProgramError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When i compile asset to run Project on ENV=production

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Error :

> ExecJS::ProgramError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>             (in /home/kop/rails/donghoxteen/vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js)
>           token ((execjs))
>           skip_line_comment ((execjs):2359:14462)
>           handle_slash ((execjs):2359:16320)
>           next_token ((execjs):2359:17382)
>           skip_line_comment ((execjs):2359:14521)
>           handle_slash ((execjs):2359:16320)
>           next_token ((execjs):2359:17382)
>           skip_line_comment ((execjs):2359:14521)
>           handle_slash ((execjs):2359:16320)
>           next_token ((execjs):2359:17382)
>           skip_line_comment ((execjs):2359:14521)
>           handle_slash ((execjs):2359:16320)
>           next_token ((execjs):2359:17382)
>           skip_line_comment ((execjs):2359:14521)
>           handle_slash ((execjs):2359:16320)
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in`block in call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in`call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in`lock'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in`run_uglifyjs'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in`evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in`block in evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in`evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in`new'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in`block in build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in`build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in`find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in`benchmark'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in`block in compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in`compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in`with_logger'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
>           V8::Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>           at token (<eval>:1:0)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14462)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           at next_token (<eval>:2359:17382)
>           at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
>           at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in`block in call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in`call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in`lock'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in`run_uglifyjs'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in`evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in`block in evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in`evaluate'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in`new'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in`block in build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in`build_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in`find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in`benchmark'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in`block in compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in`compile'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in`with_logger'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>           /home/kop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3213/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
>           Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
>           (See full trace by running task with --trace)

in my file config env=Product :

```
  Rails.application.configure do
      config.cache_classes = false
      config.eager_load = false
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
      config.active_support.deprecation = :log
      config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
      config.assets.debug = true
      config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
    end
```

How to fix this error. pls Help me
Tks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your problem seems to be a stack overflow. That is, you have too many nested function calls.

Most likely, stack overflows are caused by unintended endless [recursions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You can see that on repeating lines

```
...
at next token (<eval>:2359:17382)
at skip_line_comment (<eval>:2359:14521)
at handle_slash (<eval>:2359:16320)
...
```

You have to check, why they are called recursive and whether it is intended for them.

Comment: tks,
and How to check this ? ( im a newbie ), pls send me a key word to search  or anything  can fix error

Comment: Sorry, that I had not answered your comment yet. Although, you accepted the answer. Do you still need help or could you help yourself with this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the very similar issues by deleting an empty js file referenced by application.js